# How to change the color of background or digits in date box using jquery mobile.?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to change  the color of the background or the digits in date box. [**Here is my fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yG9E/2/).

### JavaScript/jQuery

```js
$(document).on('click', '#Cancel', function() {
   $("#AddButton").text('Add');
   $(".caseName_h").attr("readonly", false);
    $.mobile.changePage($("#Home"),{transition:'none'});
});
```

---

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to change the color of the selected date input field, or the date box itself?

[Please refer to this link](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/themes.html), there is an `inputTheme` property which can be set that could suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You must target the specific elements of the three inputs:

**[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/3yG9E/3/)**

### CSS

```
.ui-datebox-dboxin .ui-block-a > input {
    background-color:red;
}
.ui-datebox-dboxin .ui-block-b > input {
    background-color:blue;
}
.ui-datebox-dboxin .ui-block-c > input {
    background-color: green;
}
```

[image]

[**Demo version with formatted and colored text**](http://jsfiddle.net/3yG9E/4/)